# Hyper-V Replication Connection Refused / Forcibly Closed Errors on Large VMs

Tags: replication, hyper-v

I am trying to enable replication of a large-ish VM of 9TB between two new identical servers running Win Server 2022. I am able to get through config and begin initial replication, replication gets to a few percent and then stops. There are some errors in Event viewer that mention forcibly closing or refusing connections.

Servers are on the same domain, same vlan, have static IPs, firewall disabled. Connecting on port 80.

Replication seems to work (most of the time) with a small Win Server test VM.

I tried to export and copy the files to the 2nd server and begin replication from existing machine. While the VM on the second server worked after importing, replication still failed. Also used the $BypassProxyServer parameter starting rep with powershell Any ideas what the connection problem could be?

```
Hyper-V could not replicate changes for virtual machine '': An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  


Hyper-V could not replicate changes for virtual machine '' because the Replica server refused the connection. 
This may be because there is a pending replication operation in the Replica server for the same virtual machine which is taking longer than expected or has an existing connection. 

Hyper-V could not replicate changes for virtual machine '': The operation timed out
```

Answer (score -2):

To initiate the troubleshooting process, first, ensure the stability of the network connection between the two servers. Confirm that these servers can communicate seamlessly by verifying successful ping tests. Furthermore, pay close attention to any potential firewall restrictions that might obstruct the required replication ports. A comprehensive network and firewall assessment is vital to identify and address connectivity issues.

Next, delve into the Event Viewer logs on both servers. These logs serve as a valuable source of information that can pinpoint the exact nature of the replication issue. By scrutinizing these logs, you'll gain deeper insights into error messages related to forced connection closures or refusals. Armed with this information, you'll be better equipped to take targeted actions in the troubleshooting process.

Additionally, consider standard recovery measures like restarting the Hyper-V service on both servers, and if necessary, performing full server restarts. This can serve as a means to refresh the replication process and potentially resolve any lingering issues.

As you continue your efforts, contemplate the adjustment of the replication timeout value. Using the PowerShell command Set-VMReplication, modify the -ReplicationTimeout parameter to accommodate the transfer of the large 9TB VM. This ensures that the replication process is not prematurely interrupted.

In the event that the issue persists, explore the option to bypass the proxy server when initiating replication. Utilize the PowerShell command Start-VMReplication with the $BypassProxyServer parameter to streamline the replication process, mitigating any potential interference from proxy servers.

These PowerShell commands can be executed on Windows Server 2022 to help with network troubleshooting, timeout adjustments, and bypassing proxy servers. Check network connectivity (Replace  with the actual name or IP address of the target server):

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName <ServerName>
```

Adjust replication timeout (This command allows you to adjust the replication timeout for a specific VM. Replace  with the name of the VM, and  with the desired timeout value in seconds):

```
Set-VMReplication -VMName <VMName> -ReplicationTimeout <TimeoutInSeconds>
```

Bypass proxy server when starting replication (This command initiates replication for a specific VM while bypassing proxy servers. Replace  with the name of the VM):

```
Start-VMReplication -VMName <VMName> -BypassProxyServer
```